# Changing values on X-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code, which generates the following graph

```
plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
plt.title("Title", fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel("X", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("Y", fontsize=12)
plt.xlim(0, 300)
plt.ylim(0, 300)
plt.plot(x, color = 'black')
plt.plot(y, color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I remove xlim & ylim I get the following graph which includes all observations.

[image]

However, now values on x-axis represents number of data points and value on y-axis represents the variable value like sale, weight etc. I was wondering if its possible to have x & y axis same set of values like (0-250) and still get all the data points in the graph.

I think xlim & ylim are truncating the number of observations.

Here is a sample of my data

[image]

Comment: Is `y` not supposed to plot against `x`, e,g `plot(x, y)`? You plot them as two separate series. Is that what you really want?

Comment: I would like to have all the data points in graph however, the values/tick on x & y axis can be made custom.

Comment: First plot contains 300 data points. Second plot includes 800 data points. My understanding is you want to plot 800 data points within an xlim of 300?

Comment: Correct, I am not sure if that's possible.

Comment: With matplotlib and numpy you could plot this as `x = np.linspace(0, 250, len(y1))` and then `plt.plot(x, y1, color=...)` and `plt.plot(x, y2, color=...)`, supposing `y1` and `y2` would contain the values to plot.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using `plt.plot()` correctly.

You have:

```
plt.plot(x, color = 'black')
plt.plot(y, color = 'red')
```

While actually, the black and the red line represent TWO variables, each one having an array/list of x and y coordinates.

To make it clear, let's call the red one `x1` and `y1`, and the black one `x2` and `y2`.

But actually, you only need to plot `y1` and `y2`. `x1` and `x2` will be added automatically (and will correspond to the indices of `y1` and `y2`).

Then, you can plot:

```
plt.plot(y1, color = 'black')
plt.plot(y2, color = 'red')
```

Remove the line `plt.xlim(0, 300)`.
You can remove `plt.ylim(0, 300)` too, since the automatic `ylim` must be fine.

Read [the `plt.plot()` docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) for more info!

Comment: thank you for your input however, I have three variables x, y1, y2 where x represents number of data points, y1 represents actual & y2 represents estimated. Hence, I am looking to get all datapoints and their corresponding y1 & y2 values

Comment: @gis you don't need to set `x` explicitly in this case. It already understands what the X axis is—indices of elements of `y1` and `y2`. When you need the number of data points, you can just use `len(y1)` for example

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X_LIM = 300

# Sample Data
y1 = np.random.randint(12, 260, size=800)
y2 = np.random.randint(12, 260, size=800)

# Add this
x = np.arange(0,X_LIM,X_LIM/len(y1))  # Assumes both y1 and y2 are same len.

plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
plt.title("Title", fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel("X", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("Y", fontsize=12)
plt.xlim(0, X_LIM) # To the limit you specified
plt.plot(x, y1, color='black')
plt.plot(x, y2, color='red')
plt.show()

# Printing the new mapping of values to X
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':x, 'y1':y1, 'y2':y2})
print(df)

OUTPUT:
           x   y1   y2
0      0.000  132   63
1      0.375   42   59
2      0.750  222  198
3      1.125   87  146
4      1.500  229  210
..       ...  ...  ...
795  298.125   56  173
796  298.500   37  125
797  298.875   68   52
798  299.250   20  243
799  299.625  171  235

[800 rows x 3 columns]
```

[image: Plot Yield]

I believe this will achieve what you are trying to do.Although very messy and very compressed.

The `np.arange()` function is used to create an array of x-values ranging from 0 to `X_LIM` with a step size: `X_LIM/len(y1)`, which ensures that there are enough x-values to match the length of the y-values in `y1` and `y2`. These x-values are then used to plot the y1 and y2 values against the x-axis, respectively.